# eip-681 equivalent for Polkadot to generate qrcodes

Tags: polkadot, evm, assets, blockchain

I'm developing an app and there I have the possibility to generate qrcodes to ask for payments in multiple `blockchains` using multiple tokens. For EVM blockchains I do have the eip681 to guide me (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-681) the idea is the qrcode be made of the described url. I could find for bitcoin (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0021), Solana (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/SPEC.md), Stellar (https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md#operation-pay) but for Polkadot I'm searching for days with no success.

Is there something similar for Polkadot? If so, where can I find the documentation for such?